# Trying to Run Both Animations at once with Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to toggle two classes at the same time with the third button on the button rows. I have two elements that run. And no this isn't meant to be elegant, its meant to demonstrate to myself if I understand how to run two animations at the same time. Right now they run sequentially (one after the other). Is there any way to start both animations at the same time?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
// change the title size
function toggleH1S() {
 $("h1").toggleClass("big", 500, "easeOutBounce");
}

// change the title color
function toggleH1C() {
 $("h1").toggleClass("red", 500, "linear");
}

// show or hide the text and show or hide the text color changing button
function toggleP() {
 if ($("#dummy").css("display") == "block") {
  $("#dummy").slideUp("slow", "easeOutBounce");
 }
 else {
  $("#dummy").slideDown("slow", "easeOutBounce");
 }
 $("#t4").toggle("slow", "easeOutBounce");
}

// change text color
function togglePC() {
 $("#dummy").toggleClass("red", 500, "linear");
}

// single event controllers
$("#t1").click(function() {
 toggleH1S();
});
$("#t2").click(function() {
 toggleH1C();
});
$("#t3").click(function() {
 toggleP();
});
$("#t4").click(function () {
 togglePC();
});

// double even controllers
$("#t5").click(function () {
 toggleH1S();
 toggleH1C();
});
$("#t6").click(function () {
 toggleP();
 togglePC();
});
});
```

```css
/* basic styles */
body {
 font-family: verdana;
 margin: 0 10px;
 padding: 0;
}
h1 {
 display: inline-block;
}
h1,
p {
 padding: 10px;
}
/* customized buttons */
button {
 outline: none;
 padding: 3px 6px;
 font-size: 16pt;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
button,
button:link,
button:visited,
button:hover {
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ccc;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
button:active {
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px #ccc;
}

/* contextual button styles */
div.block {
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
button.both {
 background-color: #d4b2b2;
 font-weight: bold; 
 color: #700000;
}
button.sizer {
 background-color: #b6e1d2;
 color: #0E9B6C;
}
button.colorer {
 background-color: #e8cf9f;
 color: #C7880F;
}

/* styles for changes */
h1.big {
 font-size: 100px; 
}
h1.red,
p.red {
 color: #900000;
 background-color: #ddb2b2;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Sand 2</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/js_jquery.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sandy_styles.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>jQuery Sandbox</h1>
 <div class="block">
  <button id="t1" class="sizer">Grow/Shrink Title</button>
  <button id="t2" class="colorer">Change Title Color</button>
  <button id="t5" class="both">DO BOTH!</button>
 </div>
 <p id="dummy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
 <div class="block">
  <button id="t3" class="sizer">Dismiss/Summon Text</button>
  <button id="t4" class="colorer">Change Text Color</button>
  <button id="t6" class="both">DO BOTH!</button>
 </div>
</body>
</html>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm looking into this, but for future reference, read about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your example code is a bit long, especially that Lorem ipsum text.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: Nope I never did. This is more of an exercise than anything else. I probably could find a framework if I really needed to know. This is more about perfecting my skill. That being said, I probably AM going to take a stab at it today.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble getting it to work, but according to the documentation at https://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/, you should be able to call "toggleClass" with an options object. One of the optional properties is "queue". When "queue" is false, the toggle should start immediately and allow other toggles to start immediately as well.

```
var hasClass = $("h1").hasClass("big");
$("h1").toggleClass("big", !hasClass, {duration:500, easing:"easeOutBounce", queue:false});
```

It appears that only one toggleClass will actual apply when using "queue: false". The only solution I have found so far is to just toggle both classes in one call.

```
$("h1").toggleClass("big red", 500, "easeOutBounce");
```

I'll update my answer with corrections if I manage to get two simultaneous "toggleClass" calls to apply correctly.

Comment: Help thank you, I might look into that too. It might be browser specific too.